# iOS 7.1 UIModalPresentationCustom warning message

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uikit

Since I moved to **iOS 7.1** I keep getting the warning message for each one of my custom transitions. How to get rid of this:

> "UIModalPresentationCustom presentation style can only be  used with an
>   animator or with unanimated dismissals."

Comment: Do you implement `animationControllerForDismissedController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem. I had to retain the transitioning delegate in the presenting controller because it was nil when I went to dismiss from the presented controller.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourTransitioningDelegate *transitioningDelegate;

@synthesize transitioningDelegate;

transitioningDelegate = [[YourTransitioningDelegate alloc] init];

UIViewController *presentingController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
presentingController.transitioningDelegate = transitioningDelegate;
[self presentViewController:presentingController];
```

Comment: @property(nonatomic, assign) id<UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate> transitioningDelegate  // Before 7.1 maybe this property was retain

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning, but what I did was implement animationControllerForDismissedController from **UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate** protocol.

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController;
```

Comment: In which class i need to add this. In Custom class which will be call or in base class which will call custom animation ?

Comment: Put it in the same class you implement animationControllerForPresentedController:. The object returned for the dismissed controller will likely be the same as the presented controller.