# Modal custom segues in iOS 7.1 give warnings when being dismissed

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, segue, modalviewcontroller

## Background

I've made a custom segue to allow for "overlay cards" to slide down from the top, and then fly away upon dismissal. When writing the code, I realized that all examples used a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to capture when the segue was animate/dismissed. So far so good, but all examples that I found let the `presentingController` act as the delegate, which to me sounds strange since I need to "distribute" the logics of *how* my "overlay card" looks like, in two places; the custom segue, and the presenting controller.

Hence, I figured that I could combine the two into one; the custom segue, which would make my storyboard so much neater, since all view-controllers that I want to show as "overlay cards", simply are assigned the "CardSegue" that I've created, instead of having each and every presenting controller implement `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`.

## Problem

From one of the presenting controllers, I get a warning when dismissing the presented "Overlay card";

```
UIModalPresentationCustom presentation style can only be used with an animator or with unanimated dismissals.
```

I looked around, and all I could find was another post that seemed promising;
[iOS 7.1 UIModalPresentationCustom warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402965/ios-7-1-uimodalpresentationcustom-warning-message)

But, the problem is that since my custom segue IS the transitionDelegate, trying to keep it as one logical unit, I can't really apply the reasoning of retaining the delegate...? I mean, the segue is running -- hence, the delegate is alive and well. I'm missing something, or there's an obvious reason that I cannot see right now for why the `transitionDelegate` MUST be separated from the custom segue?

## My code

```
#define POPUP_MARGIN    25

@interface CardSegue () <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isPresenting) BOOL presenting;

@end

@implementation CardSegue

- (void)perform
{
    //Make sure that we are the delegate...
    [self.destinationViewController setTransitioningDelegate:self];
    [self.destinationViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCustom];

    //Brute-force show the end-result!
    [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate Methods

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                                  presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                      sourceController:(UIViewController *)source
{
    //Configure the animator
    self.presenting = YES;
    return self;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed
{
    self.presenting = NO;
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UIViewControllerContextTransitioning Methods

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.5f;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    // Grab the from and to view controllers from the context
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    if (self.presenting)
    {
        // Set our ending frame. We'll modify this later if we have to
        CGRect frame = fromViewController.view.frame;
        CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(POPUP_MARGIN, POPUP_MARGIN, frame.size.width - 2 * POPUP_MARGIN, frame.size.height - 2 * POPUP_MARGIN);
        fromViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
        toViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15;

        //toViewController.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
        toViewController.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        mainView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];

        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:mainView];
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

        CGRect startFrame = endFrame;
        startFrame.origin.y -= frame.size.height;

        toViewController.view.frame = startFrame;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
            mainView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
            fromViewController.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed;
            toViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
            toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    }
    else {
        // Set our ending frame. We'll modify this later if we have to
        CGRect frame = toViewController.view.frame;
        CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(POPUP_MARGIN, POPUP_MARGIN, frame.size.width - 2 * POPUP_MARGIN, frame.size.height - 2 * POPUP_MARGIN);
        toViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        mainView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];

        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:mainView];
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];

        endFrame.origin.y += frame.size.height;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
            toViewController.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeAutomatic;
            mainView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
            fromViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
            fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Decouple them. Probably you do not need segue at all, because you can set modalPresentationStyle in `prepareForSegue:` in presenting view controller.